# Bypass ls argument limit

Tags: bash

So, I need to list a bunch of files in reverse order from a certain directory. Only problem is that there are a lot of files in the directory (since I'm decompiling video frames in a directory to reverse the entire video) and when I run ls I get an error that says `/bin/ls argument list too long`. I was wondering how to get around this error?

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ls` doesn't do, `find -type f` is usually your friend (and can also use stuff like `-print0` to avoid problems exotic filenames).

Comment: yes, `find ...` with `| xargs commands_to_execute {} ` ... `man xargs` for more details. ... OR the `-exec` option to `find`. Good luck to all.

Comment: `xargs`... only if you cannot do it with an `-exec ...{} \;` or `-exec ..{} \+` of course :)

Comment: BTW, as your talking images (I'd look harder for a converter that can just reverse, but that's beside the point), don't forget to quote any name matches (so, `find -name *.jpg` would still give you problems, use `find -name '*.jpg'` instead).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using something like

```
ls -1 -r *.jpg
```

to produce the reverse-sorted list of images.  Since Bash sorts filename expansions (aka globs) itself, you can get the same effect by just reversing the expansion of `*.jpg`.  This is one way to do it:

```
printf '%s\n' *.jpg | tac
```

If you haven't got `tac`, you can do it all in pure Bash:

```
images=( *.jpg )
for (( i=${#images[*]}-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- )) ; do
    printf '%s\n' "${images[i]}"
done
```